# access HTML data attribute on an anchor with PrototypeJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prototypejs

I am having an issue with accessing an attribute of an anchor with PrototypeJS 1.6.0.3.

My code below works when I hard-code the course_number variable, however I would like to be able to extract it from the anchor.

This is my anchor tag:

```
<a class="course_number_info_link" data-course-number="{$foo}" href="#">{$foo}</a>
```

This is my invoke method observing a click on the anchor:

```
$$('.course_number_info_link').invoke('observe', 'click', this.getCourseInfo(this));
```

This is my `getCourseInfo` method, however the `course_number` doesn't pull through. How can I get access to the data attribute?

```
    getCourseInfo: function(element) {

       var course_number = element.readAttribute('data-course-number');

       console.log(course_number);

       new Ajax.Updater('result-' + course_number, '/ajax/get_course_info.php', {
                parameters: { course_no: course_number },
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
       });

    }
```

Comment: What is the 'element' attribute when 'getCourseInfo' is called? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'element' _argument_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way you are setting up the observer is why it is failing - you are passing a complete function to the observer instead of the function reference

If this is ran inside of your object then `this` is the object instead of the element

```
$$('.course_number_info_link').invoke('observe', 'click', this.getCourseInfo(this));
```

should be

```
$$('.course_number_info_link').invoke('observe', 'click', this.getCourseInfo);
```

the parameter that is passed into `getCourseInfo()` will be an Event object not an element object - `this` should be the element object or you can also get the element like this

```
getCourseInfo: function(event) {

   var element = event.findElement();
   var course_number = element.readAttribute('data-course-number');
//snip....
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer provided by Geek Num 88 is correct in pointing out the wrong setup of the observer, it doesn't fully explain how to correctly access the [data-* attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).
Of course the easiest way would be prototype's `Element.readAttribute()` but you can also use the native [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) which is available on all modern browsers. So instead of:

```
var course_number = element.readAttribute('data-course-number');
```

you could just use:

```
var course_number = element.dataset.courseNumber;
```

If you need a fallback for older browsers, you could implement something like this:

```
Element.addMethods({
    addDataset: function(e){
        if(!(e = $(e))){
            return;
        }
        if(!e.dataset){
            e.dataset = {};
            $A(e.attributes).each(function(a){
                if(a.name.match(/^data-/)){
                    e.dataset[a.name.substr(5).camelize()] = a.value;
                }
            });
        }
        return e;
    }
});
```